# Creating new lines on an automized message on AppleScript

Tags: applescript, reply

I am trying to create a new line in a message in my apple script code. But it keeps saying I can't add return after return. [What I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCmh.png)  [this what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PMcu.png)

my current code is

```
set myReply to "Sure. I will start doing that now." & return & "Hope everything is well." & return & "Thanks," & return & "-Diego"
```

Comment: Have you tried just having just two double quotes to wrap the whole paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to concatenate the return character. Try:

```
set myReply to "Sure Dora, I will start doing that now.
Hope everything is well

Thanks,
-Diego"
```